# Circular UIScrollView in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiscrollview

I want to implement a UIScrollView that has a circular shape in iPhone, kindly guide me so that I can make it possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's easy! Make a UIScrollView that is a perfect square, then do this:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

scrollView.layer.cornerRadius = scrollView.frame.size.width/2;
```

I might have my math wrong... I can't test it right now. If it doesn't look right, just fiddle with that cornerRadius property and you'll have a circle in no time :)

Comment: @Aurum Aquila, Its giving error, cornerRadius not a structure or union.

Comment: What are you suggesting here??

Comment: @Aditya He wants a circle, so we round to corners with a radius of half of the length of the view. This makes it look like a circle.

Comment: Oh i see..then the question should be asked bit more clearly man!

Comment: @Aurum, I have imported QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h, actually the error is cornerRadius in not the member of scrollView.

Comment: @Aditya Yeah, he should have explained the circular part better. But it's not a huge deal. Your answer might be useful for someone on google. Leave it there.

Comment: Arman, is your `UIScrollView` even called `scrollView`? You gotta change it to the name of your object, then import it. cornerRadius is a member of UIView, so everything from UIButton to UIWebView can use it.

Comment: @Aurum, I have outlet, IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView; I just write your code in my viewDidLoad. But not working.

Answer (score 2):

The strategy I would take is to duplicate the first view and make it also the view after the last view. Once that "fake" first view is shown, shift all the subviews so that the real first view is where the "fake" first view was. Your users won't even know you switched.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm.. I guess I didn't get your question. What I suggested is basically what Aditya's link says -- having duplicate ends. Sorry this didn't answer your question!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/creating-circular-and-infinite-uiscrollviews.html) link.It will serve your purpose...

Yu can also download the sample code from there for better understanding...

Cheers

Comment: I don't want to duplicate ends, I want to make UIScrollView in Circular Shape.